# Event time on Google analytic

Tags: google-analytics

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var timeStamp = (hours + ":" + minutes + " ");</script>

onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'cata', 'act', 'label','timeStamp '])"
```

I am trying to pass the current time as a value but i cannot get it work
any idea

Answer (score 0):

because the value parameter should be number not string!